# Proof of something involving matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just been reading my friends notes from a class I miss and it says for any vector $a = \left( \matrix{
  x \hfill \cr 
  y \hfill \cr 
  z \hfill \cr}  \right)$, ${M_a}$ is defined to be the matrix:
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   0 & { - z} & y  \cr 
   z & 0 & { - x}  \cr 
   { - y} & x & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Then $${M_a}{M_b} - {M_b}{M_a} = {M_{a \times b}}$$

which is kind of cool. How would I prove it?

Comment: I don't know why the matrix isn't rendering. If anyone can correct the code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: what is $M_b$? here

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could just calculate it out, letting $b=\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\u\\v\end{array}\right)$.

Then, assuming $a\times b$ is the cross product, $a\times b=\left(\begin{array}{c}yv-zu\\tz-xv\\xu-yv\end{array}\right)$.

Then just compare $M_a M_b-M_b M_a$ to $M_{a\times b}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle a=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ b=\begin{pmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix}$. Now $$a\times b=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1z_2-z_1y_2 \\ z_1x_2-z_2x_1 \\ x_1y_2-x_2y_1\end{pmatrix} \\ \Downarrow \\ M_{a\times b}=\begin{pmatrix}0&x_2y_1-x_1y_2&z_1x_2-z_2x_1 \\ x_1y_2-x_2y_1&0&z_1y_2-z_2y_1 \\ z_2x_1-z_1x_2&y_1z_2-y_2z_1&0\end{pmatrix} \\[1cm] M_a=\begin{pmatrix}0&-z_1&y_1 \\ z_1& 0& -x_1\\ -y_1&x_1&0\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ M_b=\begin{pmatrix}0&-z_2&y_2 \\ z_2&0&-x_2 \\ -y_2&x_2&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now you can evaluate $M_aM_b-M_bM_a$ and get the required result.